# Form switching color when text is entered (CSS)

Tags: css, forms, web, placeholder

I have a form with a video in the background. When no text is entered in the input boxes I want them to have opacity 0. But when the value is not zero, I want them to have a background color. I was thinking that I could use placeholder for this.

Now I only have the background color showing when the input is in focus as you can see below

```css
.for_ajax_contact #contactform input[type="text"]:focus, .for_ajax_contact #contactform textarea:focus {
 outline-width: 0;
 background-color: #fff;
 opacity: 0.8;
 transition: all 0.3s linear 0s !important;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear 0s !important;
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Could you add full code example?

Comment: You might have to use javascript to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without JavaScript, but there's a catch. You'll need to use the HTML5 `required` attribute on the `textarea`/`input` and style the `:valid` pseudoclass on each form element.

```css
input,
textarea {
  background: white;
}

input:valid,
textarea:valid {
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input required type="text">

<textarea required></textarea>
```

If this isn't preferred, you'll need to go the JavaScript route, as a commenter suggested.

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS pseudo-class `:placeholder-shown` that detects whether or not the placeholder is present. Unfortunately, this is in the specification for [CSS Level 4](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#placeholder) and it only works in WebKit browsers at the time of writing.

```css
input:placeholder-shown {
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Test" />
```